# How to extract html page from a response using mozilla add-on sdk APIs?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, add-on

I am creating an Add-on for Mozilla Firefox using Mozilla Add-on SDK , for that I need to parse the HTML page that I get as response when I request for a web page. So that after parsing the whole web page , I can to run a segmentation process on it. So that I can redisplay it on the screen by editing them as much as required. So , please give me a solution to , store or parse the HTML page so that I can edit it dynamically and redisplay it. How do I retrieve only the HTML page from the response.

Answer (score 0):

If by "response" you mean the response of `XMLHttpRequest`, then you get the 'responseText' and use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to covert it into DOM.
Then you can make the changes and display.

If by "response" you mean when a page is loading, then you can run the code of the addon, before, as soon as, or after DOM is loaded and make the changes to the display as required.

More information is required for a more comprehensive reply.

**Update on new info**
You can run the script in the addon, based on URL by using `PageMod`

[PageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod)
[Modifying Web Pages Based on URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL)
[util/match-pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I meant "response" as in where , whenever a user requests for a web page by entering in the URL of a website , I need that response that he gets to pass through my Add-on to filter and display as required.

Comment: That is common. I will add more info to my post now

Comment: Sure , I'll try that out and let you know if that works for me.